how to cast ClassA.class?
I had model class that takes up generic type "T"
@Component
public class ClassAModel<T>{
    private String id;
    private ClassBModel<T> data;
}

@Component
public class ClassBModel<T>{
    private String something;
    private List<T> result;
}

I want to make a GET method API call to retrieve that has nested object
{
    "id":"12345",
    "data" : {
         "something": "abcde",
         "result": [
                 {...},{...},{...}
         ]
    }
}

API call code
responseEntity = commonUtil
                    .getRestClient()
                    .get()
                    .uri(UtilConstant.URI)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .retrieve()
                    .toEntity(ClassAModel<ClassCResponseModel>.class); //This is where I get an error

So how to pass a cast .class context to toEntity() method?

Also, is your error a compile-time error (where casting may in fact help), or is it a run-time exception (where casting wouldn't help at all)? Please post the complete error message with your question.

ClassAModel<ClassCResponseModel>.class - you can't do that, period.
Depending on the exact library used (it's unclear), a workaround with a subclass to define the exact generic parameter, might be possible.
public class DeserializationHack extends ClassAModel<ClassCResponseModel> {
}

Use this class to supply the class to deserialize into.
responseEntity = commonUtil
                    .getRestClient()
                    .get()
                    .uri(UtilConstant.URI)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .retrieve()
                    .toEntity(DeserializationHack.class);

